# Выбило такая проблема для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Transform.Translate требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedx;
    public float verticalImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            speedx = -horizontalSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            speedx = horizontalSpeed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        Transform.Translate(speedx, 0, 0);
        speedx = 0;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Нажата была не A и не D. И `speedx` не инициализировалась. Задайте дефолтное значение:  `float speedx=0;`

Comment: @Zufir Это, конечно, возможно, но к "Выбило такая проблема" не имеет отношения.

Comment: Не понял в чем проблема . Код начал изучать только сегодня. Прошу сказать в каком именно месте проблема .

Comment: @Дмитрий Вам что, не виден ответ?

Comment: Честно говоря нет так как только начал

Comment: а нет уже все хорошо большое спасибо

Comment: @Дмитрий Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Transform.Translate(speedx, 0, 0);
transform.Translate(speedx, 0, 0);
```